# Access AWS Cognito pool from another account using NodeJS( server side)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We are working on an application where we have two kind of users

1. Individual user( allowed to signup themselves).
2. Users part of an Agency( added to application only by the admin who are our internal
   users).

The application is designed in such a way that all the Cognito operations like adding user, deleting user,password reset etc are done by Server api(**Server Side Authentication Flow**) running in **AWS Lambda**. We do not do anything at the client side.

Our infrastructure team is currently making changes in way where all the applications will be running under their own AWS account but we do not want to create user pool in each accounts as many of our applications share the same user pool. So we decided to keep the pool in the current account and move only the applications to their respective accounts.

We do know how to connect to a pool from different account from NodeJS and assuming that we created all the respective roles and permission, we even tried using the full ARN of the pool id but the api does not allow ARN, it needs only the pool id and if we use just pool id,it throws an error saying

> pool does not exists

which we believe is because it is looking at the current account instead of another account where the pool resides.

Please advise

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use the AWS SDK inside NodeJS to connect to the Cognito User Pool.

The AWS SDK will somehow pick up credentials to authenticate with the AWS servers for a certain AWS account. If you don't specify an access code / secret key in your code (which I hope is not the case!) the SDK will probably pick up (temporary) keys from the environment.

You can setup an IAM role if you're running NodeJS in a Lambda or ECS container. If you do this, AWS will create some temporary credentials and inject them via environment variables.

To connect to a different AWS account, in general you have two options:

1. Use a resource policy in the other AWS account resource to provide access to the running AWS account
2. Provide credentials to your application manually, e.g. by adding secure environment variables in Lambda, that can be used to access another IAM user in another AWS account.

Option 1 is not possible at this moment for Cognito User Pools (you can check [this table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html#admin_svcs) to see which services support this).

Option 2 is possible for your scenario, the main trick is to provide credentials in a secure way. How to do this depends on your specific environment, but a possiblity in Lambda is using secure environment variables or SSM params.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Our lambda accesses other resources based on the role but if the cross account resource access cannot  be done via roles we can definitely use credentials.Since our application configuration details are already stored in ssm , I can add credentials to the ssm. I hope just passing the credentials to the Cognito api should suffice to connect to the pool. I will try tonight and update back.